# Virtual function in copy constructor

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have parent abstract class **BinaryTree**. Here is its copy constructor.

```
BinaryTree::BinaryTree(const BinaryTree & other) {
    .....
    //here about 10 setters
    .....
    if (other.getLeft() != nullptr) {
        this->setLeft(new BinaryTree(other.getLeftConstReference()));
    } else {
        this->setLeft(nullptr);
    }
    if (other.getRight() != nullptr) {
        this->setRight(new BinaryTree(other.getRightConstReference()));
    } else {
        this->setRight(nullptr);
    }
}
```

I don't want rewrite this constructor in my child class wholly. Because that 10 setters I have to write in all my child classes constructors. So I desided write virtual function **getHeirNodePointer(BinaryTree & node)** in parent class and override it in child class

```
ChildBinaryTree * ChildBinaryTree::getHeirNodePointer(BinaryTree & node) {
    return new ChildBinaryTree(node);
}
```

Now my copy constructor in parent class looks like that

```
BinaryTree::BinaryTree(const BinaryTree & other) {
    .....
    //here about 10 setters
    .....
    if (other.getLeft() != nullptr) {
        this->setLeft(this->getHeirNodePointer(other.getLeftConstReference()));
    } else {
        this->setLeft(nullptr);
    }
    if (other.getRight() != nullptr) {
        this->setRight(this->getHeirNodePointer(other.getRightConstReference()));
    } else {
        this->setRight(nullptr);
    }
}
```

But I got an error that virtual functions in constructor are not available.

Tell me please is there any way to avoid doubling of my code in my child copy constructors? Or I must repeat all setters in this constructor in each my child class?  Copy assignment (operator=) is busy already.

Comment: Put this code in a member function of `BinaryTree` that is called from the derived class constructors.

Comment: Use a **factory function** that constructs the object, then calls the virtual function to complete the construction of the object.

Comment: Why this doesn't work: The base class constructs before the derived classes really get started. The derived class doesn't exist yet so it's V-Table, or whatever trick is used for the polymorphic book-keeping, hasn't been set up.

Comment: Thank you all. Went to try. Have a nice day!!!